# Java give a possible list for a parameter

Tags: java, list, methods, parameters

I want to create a parameter with multiple possibilities. To be more precise, in the method, I would like to have different levels of warning like 0,1,2 and 3. When you type it gives you have only these 4 possibilities.

Eg: setFoobar(1, "Yo");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using an [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for that:

```
public enum Severity {
    DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR
}
```

[edit] Imagine, you have some method for logging a message with different urgency. The `enum` signifies that. In your method, you could then do something like:

```
switch (severity) {
    case DEBUG:
        // ignore
        break;
    case INFO:
        System.out.println(message);
        break;
    case WARN:
    case ERROR:
        System.err.println(message);
        break;
}
```

... or just do some comparisons:

```
if (severity == Severity.WARN || severity == Severity.ERROR) {
    System.err.println(message);
}
```

Beside that, an `enum` is much like a normal `class`, which means that you can add state (as in instance variables) and methods. For example, you could move the logic given above directly into the `enum` like so:

```
public enum Severity {

    DEBUG("Some low-level logging output"), 
    INFO("Informational output"), 
    WARN("A warning"), 
    ERROR("A serious error");

    private String description;

    private Severity(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void output(String message) {
        switch (this) {
            case DEBUG:
                // ignore
                break;
            case INFO:
                System.out.println(message);
                break;
            case WARN:
            case ERROR:
                System.err.println(message);
                break;
        }
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know good examples because I don't know much about enums

Comment: I don't know much how to implement them after in the method. I ddi look to the javadocs but they are ussless. Could you explain or if you knew good tutorials on how to use enums?

Comment: @3751_Creator Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Java [`enums`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) can provide this type of functionality.